# 'Greedy' negative look-behind - don't match if preceded by word

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I don't want to match `bar` if preceded by `foo` within the past 20 characters, so I tried doing `(?!foo).{0,20}bar`. This doesn't work because `oobar` is a valid match.

If I anchor the pattern e.g. `the (?!foo).{0,20}bar` then `the foobar` doesn't match. However, in my use case `foobar` could be preceded by any number of arbitrary characters, so there is nothing to anchor it to.

In a way I want to make the negative look-behind more 'greedy' or rather less 'lenient', but I'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: In .NET, JS ECMAScript 2018 or Python PyPi you may use `(?<!foo.{0,20})bar`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to use the Python `re` module so unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: Then you cannot use a regex, or purely regex for this.

Comment: Well you could use `(?<!foo)(?<!foo.)(?<!foo.{2})(?<!foo.{3})[...](?<!foo.{19})(?<!foo.{20})bar` if you really insist on using regex...

Comment: @SebastianProske Nice one, it can be generated dynamically, so some code will still be necessary. And probably a `re.DOTALL` flag would come handy then.